# mq_open: Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

I'm trying to run the example program for POSIX message queues found in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_notify) for mq_notify. I'm running it as `./mq '/bla'` and it gives me the error `mq_open: Invalid argument`.

This is the line in the sample program that gives the error:

```
mqdes = mq_open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
```

I've tried changing it to

```
mqdes = mq_open("/bla", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
```

but it still doesn't work.

This must be simple, but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

This is RHEL 5.8, by the way.

**EDIT:** I was wrong about the first error. Without O_CREAT, it said "No such file or directory". I guess it was trying to open a message queue that didn't exist. With O_CREAT, I think the invalid argument error was because I only had two arguments, and you need four with O_CREAT.

Comment: Post the strace output of that example program. Note though, if you change it to use `O_CREAT`, you need to pass 2 additional arguments to mq_open(). e.g. `mq_open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);`

Comment: @nos Oh, that fixed it. I think I was wrong about my first error. If I didn't have O_CREAT, it said "No such file" or something. When I added O_CREAT, I guess the "invalid argument" was argument 3 or 4, which were missing. Thanks. I can accept this as an answer if you want to write it up as one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just `mq_open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);` should fail with "ENOENT (No such file or directory)" if the message queue does not exist.

If you change it to use O_CREAT, you need to pass 2 additional arguments to [mq_open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/mq_open.html)(). (read the paragraph about O_CREAT).e.g.

```
    mq_open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
```